# Objective C: member variables and arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, double, int

i have this variables (int and double-array)

.h-File

```
@interface MyCLass : NSObject
{
 int myInt;
double paramStack[100];
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int myInt;
//@property (nonatomic, assign) double paramStack; //<- ?
```

.m-File

```
@synthesise myInt;
//@synthesize paramStack; //<- ?
```

I want the int and the double-array-variable accessible from other classes via properties.
For the int-var. it looks fine, but the array throws errors at .m-file (@synthsize) and at h.file (@property (nonatomic, assign) double paramStack).

How can i define 
"@property (nonatomic, assign) double paramStack;" as a double-array?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the property with a pointer:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) double *paramStack;
```

You can just use it like this:

```
NSLog(@"%f", self.paramStack[20]);
```

This is mainly because an array cannot be returned, but a pointer can. I.E. this getter would be impossible and that's why you cannot create an array property:

```
- (double[100])paramStack;
```